# jplayer size parameter display right dimensions black box above player

Tags: jquery, parameters, size, jplayer

i'm testing jpayler plugin with playlist addon and encountered an issue whike editing a demo source file. I've try to set the **size** parameter like this:

```
size: {
       width: "600px",
       height: "300px"
      }
```

But, it result in this:

http://tinypic.com/r/29d8g87/6

This parameter seems to resize the container where videos/posters are displayed, but playlist and player interface keeps the same dimension. Since the second player of demo file display only audio media with no posters, i understand the black box. 
Is there a parameter to set the whole player dimension (including playlist) or should i edit skin's css?

the demo file i used is "demo-02-multi-bm.htm" from http://jplayer.org/latest/jQuery.jPlayer.2.1.0.demos.zip